# Remove line containing certain string and the following line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, replace

I use this

`cat foo.txt | sed '/bar/d'`

to remove lines containing the string `bar` in the file.

I would like however to remove those lines *and the line directly after it*. Preferably in `sed`, `awk` or other tool that's available in MinGW32.

It's a kind of reverse of what I can get in `grep` with `-A` and `-B` to print matching lines as well as lines before/after the matched line.

Is there any easy way to achieve it?

Comment: Just for information: I'm analyzing logs in which entries are two-liners. So I want to find an entry matching the pattern and remove it as well as the next line. Hence I don't need to handle consecutive match lines, but thanks anyway for the completeness of your answers!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you have GNU sed (so non-embedded Linux or Cygwin):

```
sed '/bar/,+1 d'
```

If you have `bar` on two consecutive lines, this will delete the second line without analyzing it. For example, if you have a 3-line file `bar`/`bar`/`foo`, the `foo` line will stay.

Comment: +1 for the length :) In my particular example I don't have consecutive `bar`s so this one is super easy to remember.

Comment: `sed '/bar/d'` if you just want to "Remove line containing certain string" and **not** the next.

Comment: If I want to remove all the lines after math then?

Comment: @Pandya That's different. You can use e.g. `sed '/math/q'`

Comment: @Gilles Thanks that worked, but I might have done some mistake and asked [the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427711/66803).

Comment: To break down the command: the first part `/bar/,+1/` is a sed address (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses) that says start at the regexp `/bar/`, then a `,` as a separator between start/end addresses, and end `+1` lines (from the start). Then the `d` is the command (delete)

Comment: I actually wanted to delete the matching line so I just replaced +1 with +0 and it worked! like: sed '/bar/,+0 d'

Comment: @A.K. If you just want to delete the matching line, it's even simpler: `sed '/bar/d'`

Comment: I have tired `-1` for the previos line but it did not work

Answer (score 19):

If `bar` may occur on consecutive lines, you could do:

```
awk '/bar/{n=2}; n {n--; next}; 1' < infile > outfile
```

which can be adapted to delete more than 2 lines by changing the 2 above with the number of lines to delete including the matching one.

If not, it's easily done in `sed` with [@MichaelRollins' solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56134/22565) or:

```
sed '/bar/,/^/d' < infile > outfile
```

Comment: The other plus in the AWK solution is that I can replace `/bar/` with `/bar|baz|whatever/`. In `sed` that syntax doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @jakub.g , I have GNU sed (v4.4 now). Not sure about the others. What I know is that it uses "basic" regular expression syntax by default this is why your example didn't work. To achieve what you want you can either put a backslash in front of each vertical line or you can ask `sed` to use "extended" regular expressions. More information here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html#BRE-vs-ERE . Please note that this is applicable to `grep` as well.
Here's my own working example: `echo $'0a\n1b\n2c' | sed '/0a\|1b/d'`.

Answer (score 14):

I am not fluent in sed, but it is easy to do so in awk:

```
awk '/bar/{getline;next} 1' foo.txt
```

The awk script reads: for a line containing bar, get the next line (getline), then skip all subsequent processing (next). The 1 pattern at the end prints the remaining lines.

#### Update

As pointed out in the comment, the above solution did not work with consecutive `bar`. Here is a revised solution, which takes it into consideration:

```
awk '/bar/ {while (/bar/ && getline>0) ; next} 1' foo.txt
```

We now keep reading to skip all the /bar/ lines.

Comment: To replicate `grep -A` 100%, you also need to handle any number of consecutive `bar` lines correctly (by removing the whole block and 1 line after).

Answer (score 9):

You will want to make use of sed's scripting capabilities to accomplish this.

```
$ sed -e '/bar/ { 
 $!N
 d
 }' sample1.txt
```

Sample data:

```
$ cat sample1.txt 
foo
bar
biz
baz
buz
```

The "N" command appends the next line of input into the pattern space. This combined with the line from the pattern match (/bar/) will be the lines that you wish to delete. You can then delete normally with the "d" command.

Comment: How do I type a newline in console? Or this is script-only?

Comment: @jakub.g: with GNU sed: `sed -e '/bar/{N;d}' sample1.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If any line immediately following a match should be removed then your `sed` program will have to consider consecutive matches. In other words, if you remove a line following a match which also matches, then probably you should remove the line following that as well.

It is implemented simply enough - but you have to look-behind a little.

```
printf %s\\n     0 match 2 match match \
                 5 6 match match match \
                 10 11 12 match 14 15  |
sed -ne'x;/match/!{g;//!p;}'
```

---

```
0
6
11
12
15
```

It works by swapping hold and pattern spaces for each line read in - so the last line can be compared to the current each time. So when `sed` reads a line it exchanges the contents of its buffers - and the previous line is then the contents of its edit buffer, while the current line is put in hold space.

So `sed` checks the previous line for a match to *`match`*, and if its `!` not found the two expressions in the `{` function `}` are run. `sed` will `g`et the hold space by overwriting the pattern space - which means the current line is then in both the hold and pattern spaces - and then it will `//` check it for a match to its most recently compiled regular expression - *`match`* - and if *it* does not *`match`* it is `p`rinted.

This means a line is only printed if it does not *`match`* *and* the immediately previous line does not *`match`*. It also foregoes any unnecessary swaps for sequences of *`match`*es.

If you wanted a version that could drop an arbitrary number of lines occurring after a *`match`* it would need a little more work:

```
printf %s\\n    1 2 3 4 match  \
                match match 8  \
                9 10 11 12 13  \
                14 match match \
                17 18 19 20 21 |
sed -net -e'/match/{h;n;//h;//!H;G;s/\n/&/5;D;}' -ep
```

...replace the 5 with the number of lines *(including the matched line)* that you would like to remove...

---

```
1
2
3
4
12
13
14
21
```