# How to delete a specific line and the following blank line using GNU sed?

Tags: sed

I have the following text:

```
Start-Date: 2013-11-11  07:43:49
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends catfish

Start-Date: 2013-11-11  11:27:07

Start-Date: 2013-10-16  22:53:02

Start-Date: 2013-10-16  22:55:16

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  22:41:09

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  22:42:02

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  22:42:33

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  22:46:01

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:00:06
Commandline: apt-get install shimmer-themes

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:01:52
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends gedit
```

I would like to delete lines beginning with "Start-Date" and the following blank line. In other words, I would like to have just:

```
Start-Date: 2013-11-11  07:43:49
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends catfish

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:00:06
Commandline: apt-get install shimmer-themes

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:01:52
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends gedit
```

I hope my question isn't a duplicate of [Remove line containing certain string and the following line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56123/15760)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed '/^Start-Date:/ {N; /\n$/d}'
```

sed's a Stream Editor, slurp up/identify line gaggles and have your way with them.

`N` is "append a newline and the next input line to the current buffer", so `\n` in the buffer is the start of an appended line `/\n$/d` means "if the last appended line in the buffer is empty just drop all of it".

Answer (score 1):

`awk` could help:

```
$ awk '{if ($1=="Commandline:") {printf "%s\n%s\n\n", l,$0}; l=$0}' test.txt 
Start-Date: 2013-11-11  07:43:49
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends catfish

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:00:06
Commandline: apt-get install shimmer-themes

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:01:52
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends gedit
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $last,"$_\n" if /^Commandline/; $last=$_' foo.txt 
Start-Date: 2013-11-11  07:43:49
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends catfish

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:00:06
Commandline: apt-get install shimmer-themes

Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:01:52
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends gedit
```

Or, to remove blank lines:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $last,$_ if /^Commandline/; $last=$_' foo 
Start-Date: 2013-11-11  07:43:49
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends catfish
Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:00:06
Commandline: apt-get install shimmer-themes
Start-Date: 2013-10-17  23:01:52
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends gedit
```

The `-n` switch causes `perl` to process an input file line by line, saving each line in the special variable `$_`. The scriptlet above prints the current line (`$_`) and the previous line (`$last`) if the current one starts with `Commandline`. It then saves the current line as `$last` and moves to the next line.

Comment: For the record, this can be golfed with "paragraph mode": `perl -n00le 'print unless /^Start-Date.*\z/m' file` With the side effect of adding an extra blank line at the end of the file.